# Conditions of parameter $\lambda$ ensuring integral is 0

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, limits

Let $1 \le p \le \infty$. I am seeking to find the values of the parameter $\lambda$ such that:
$$\displaystyle \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \frac{1}{\epsilon^\lambda} \int_{0}^{\epsilon} f = 0 \ \ \forall f \in L^{p}[0,1]$$

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As this is homework, I will try to give some hints rather than spelling out the whole thing:

- Let's figure out, for which $\lambda$, the limit will for sure go to zero. To see this, rewrite the above integral as
  $$ \frac{1}{\epsilon^{\lambda}} \int_0^{\epsilon} f = \frac{1}{\epsilon^{\lambda}} \int_0^1 f(x) \chi_{[0,\epsilon]} \, dx,$$
  where $\chi$ is the indicator function. Now apply a well-known inequality that allows you to relate the above expression to $\|f\|_{L^p}$. You should find that if $\lambda$ is small enough, we're good to go.
- If $\lambda$ is too large, we expect the limit won't go to zero, since we'll be dividing by a large power of a small number. So what remains to be shown is that, when $\lambda$ is *larger* than the threshold determined in the above step, the limit diverges for at least one $f$. So try to find a particular $f \in L^p$ such that the limit diverges. Hint: For which $\alpha$ is $x^{\alpha} \in L^p[0,1]$?

Comment: Using Holder I get that the original expression is $\le \frac{1}{\epsilon^{\lambda}}\|f\|_p$. It seems to me that no matter the value of $\lambda$ this thing will always be infinite. What am I missing?

Comment: You're missing a term. What is the $L^q$ norm of $\chi_{[0,\epsilon]}$?

Comment: Would it be $\sqrt[q]{\epsilon}$?

Comment: Yes! So Holder's should give you that your integral is bounded by $\epsilon^{-\lambda} \epsilon^{1/q} \|f\|_p$ And $1/p + 1/q = 1$, so...

Comment: Could you give an counter-example for $\lambda=1/q$

Comment: @S.Wei Pick $f(x) = x^{-1/p}$.

Comment: But $f(x)=x^{-1/p}\not \in L^p[0,1]$, since $\int_{[0,1]} |f|^p=\int_{[0,1] }1/x\rightarrow \infty $?

Comment: @S.Wei Ah you're right. I'll have to think further.